# SDL2-CS GetKeyboardState IntPtr to byte array

Tags: c#, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 in my project and am using the C# bindings. I am trying to get the UInt8/Byte array of key scancodes from the `GetKeyboardState()` function. However, whenever I have tried, it just returns a 0.

I was wondering if anyone else had a similar experience or if you would know whats wrong with my code.

The Array is returned as an IntPtr, hence the unsafe code. (I'm not sure if I should be using the `Marshal.Copy()` function)

```cs
 public bool GetKey(SDL.SDL_Keycode _keycode)
        {

            int arraySize;
            bool isKeyPressed = false;
            byte keycode = (byte)SDL.SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(_keycode);
            bool found = false;
            unsafe
            {
                var KeyState = (byte*) SDL.SDL_GetKeyboardState(out arraySize);
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
                {
                    isKeyPressed = KeyState[i] == keycode;
                }
            }

            return isKeyPressed;
        }
```

For anyone who don't know what SDL2-CS is or what SDL2 is, but still want to help, here are the relevant links:

https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS

https://wiki.libsdl.org/

Comment: The for-loop doesn't make sense, it always sets isKeyPressed to the state of last key.  Typically that's one you will never press.  You *probably* meant isKeyPressed = KeyState[keycode];

Comment: Thank you. That got me in the right direction. The for loop was pretty stupid of me...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans Passant.

C# for whatever reason doesn't take 1 as true when placed into a Boolean, so I had to extend the statement a little.

Working Code:

```cs
public bool GetKey(SDL.SDL_Keycode _keycode)
        {
            int arraySize;
            bool isKeyPressed = false;
            IntPtr origArray = SDL.SDL_GetKeyboardState(out arraySize);
            byte[] keys = new byte[arraySize];
            byte keycode = (byte) SDL.SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(_keycode);
            Marshal.Copy(origArray, keys, 0, arraySize);
            isKeyPressed = keys[keycode] == 1;
            return isKeyPressed;
        }
```

And to remove the need for unsafe code, I used the `Marshal.Copy()` function.